# Correct method on passing PHP variables that contains date and time to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, date, datetime, parameters

I'm a bit confuse on passing PHP variables that contains date on an onclick attribute of a button, for example.. (for some reason, I put the button inside an echo)

```
<?php
$date = date("F-d-Y", "2015-07-24"); //to convert the string 2015-07-24 to date with an specific format
echo "<button onclick = 'goToThisJSMethod(".$date.")'> Pass </button>";
?>
```

on the javascript part wherein goToThisJSMethod written.

```
function goToThisJSMethod(dateRec){
 alert (dateRec);
}
```

The syntax above results nothing and the alert box didn't appear

I tried changing the above code, I alter the parameter that will be passed on PHP, instead of using `$date` variable, I used the exact string of the date to be the parameter and change the javascript like this:

```
function goToThisJSMethod(dateRec){
    var date = new Date(dateRec);
    alert(date.getMonth()+1 " " + date.getDate() + " " + date.getFullYear());
}
```

Yes there's a result  with this but then again, it returns a default date of `1/1/1970`. What should I do regarding with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem is the second argument to [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) has to be a timestamp, so you need to use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php). You'll always get "January-01-1970" because you're passing it a string where it needs a timestamp.

You probably also need quotes around your string, as below. Check the rendered HTML in the browser to see.

```
<?php
$date = date("F-d-Y", strtotime("2015-07-24")); 
echo "<button onclick=\"goToThisJSMethod('{$date}')\"> Pass </button>";
?>
```

I converted your html to use `"` and PHP to use variable interpolation.

Comment: You're welcome @NielSinel :) Don't forget to mark as answer :)